# Scala string to array to string with quoted elements

Tags: scala

In Scala, how can I convert a comma separated string to an array to a quoted string?

E.g. in R I'd use:

```
> bold_statement_string  <- "narcos,is,maybe,better,than,the,wire"
[1] "narcos,is,maybe,better,than,the,wire"
> bold_statement_array  <- strsplit(bold_statement_string, ',')[[1]]
[1] "narcos" "is"     "maybe"  "better" "than"   "the"    "wire"  
> cat(paste(shQuote(bold_statement_array), collapse = ','))
'narcos','is','maybe','better','than','the','wire'
```

In Scala, it worked with:

```
var bold_statement_string = "narcos,is,maybe,better,than,the,wire"
var bold_statement_array = bold_statement.split(',')
s"'${bold_statement_array.mkString("','")}'"
Out[83]:
'narcos','is','maybe','better','than','the','wire'
```

In python I hear there's always a pythonic way of doing it. Is there a more Scala-esk way of doing it? Or should I just rejoice in having found a solution, no matter if it could be more elegant?

Answer (score 12):

First, in Scala we use val instead of var.  We like to embrace the immutability thing where ever we can.

```
val bold_statement_string = "narcos,is,maybe,better,than,the,wire"
```

second you do not need to use string interpolation, mkString can take a prefix and a postfix which gives us:

```
bold_statement_string.split(",").mkString("'", "', '", "'")
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:
    for array:

```
scala> bold_statement_string.split(",") map {"\'%s\'".format(_)}
res8: Array[String] = Array('narcos', 'is', 'maybe', 'better', 'than', 'the', 'wire')
```

For String:

```
 scala> bold_statement_string.split(",") map {"\'%s\'".format(_)} mkString ","
res9: String = 'narcos','is','maybe','better','than','the','wire'
```

Comment: There is a three argument version of `mkString` that takes care of everything: `bold_statement_string.split(',').mkString("'", "','", "'")`.

Answer (score 0):

In the example proposed, splitting the string by comma and reconstructing the string with comma, results in the identical initial string. For the case of simply *wrapping* the string with single quotes, consider this use of `mkString`

```
bold_statement_string.mkString("'","","'")
```

which treats the string as a `Seq[Char]`, and prepends and appends the single quote characters.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the simplest way.

```
val bold_statement_string = "narcos,is,maybe,better,than,the,wire"
bold_statement_string
  .split(",")              // Split with comma
  .map("'" + _  + "'")     // Wrap with single quote
  .mkString(","))          // make string with comma
```

Answer (score -1):

Here is a more generic version that uses a typical Scala approach using map to quote the array elements and foldLeft to combine them back together.

```
val arr = bold_statement_string.split(",").map( v => s"'$v'" )

arr.foldLeft("")( (soFar,v) => if (v=="") v else soFar + ", " + v )
    // fold left starts with the value "" and then invokes the function
    // provided for every element in the collection which combines them
    // 
    // ("","'narcos'") goes to "'narcos'"
    // ("'narcos'", "'is'") goes to "'narcos', 'is'"
    // ("'narcos', 'is'", "'maybe'") goes to "'narcos', 'is', 'maybe'" 
    // and so on 
    // up to the last element giving us the target string
    // 'narcos', 'is', 'maybe', 'better', 'than', 'the', 'wire'
```

and here is a variant that works in the same way but rather than use if/else it uses the more functional Scala match.

```
bold_statement_string.split(",").map( v => s"'$v'" ).foldLeft("") {
  case ("",v) => v
  case (soFar,v) => s"$soFar, $v"
}
```